# Maximum/Minimum physical address - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How come that the given virtual address (Just an example):

The virtual address `ffffffffa08f9533` corresponds to the physical address: `0x24a5adff8`

I only have 0x200000000 (8gb) amount of physical memory (Assuming the first address is zero - probably wrong assumption) so the returned physical address is outside of my real physical memory. What am I doing wrong?

The functions I use are:

`virt_to_phys` & `phys_to_virt`

Thanks

Comment: I'm skeptical that *" virtual address `ffffffffa08f9533` corresponds to the physical address: `0x24a5adff8`"*.  They're not even on the same byte boundary!  Wouldn't you need a page size of one byte to get an unaligned mapping?

Comment: This is actually a guest virtual address (Some running user process - under hypervisor) so the addresses do make sense. EDIT: and that is not the point. look at the answer below.

Comment: Virtual machine versus bare metal, or real memory versus memory-mapped device registers should not matter: virtual memory mappings are not to the byte address.  The mapping (table) is physical memory page address to virtual memory page address.  Can you please provide the contents of the file `/proc/iomem` of this system? (Add it to your original question above, using [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27706618/edit).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCs have some address spaces which are not related to real RAM. A few days ago, I installed graphics card with 4GB of RAM. But there are other devices in the PC with their own memory which the CPU can still access: RAID controllers, network cards, I/O cards which support DMA.

In pre-64bit times, those memory areas had to be mapped somewhere in the physical address space of the RAM. Which meant you could install more than 3.5GB RAM in your PC but you couldn't use it.

With 64bit CPUs, all those memory areas can now be mapped somewhere outside of your real/normal RAM.

On Linux, you can get the current layout of the 64bit physical memory in `/proc/iomem`

Related: [Getting memory map of every device in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334596/getting-memory-map-of-every-device-in-linux)

Comment: Ehm, That is not what I asked. I'm translating a kernel virtual address to a kernel physical address and I'm receiving an address which is larger than my maximum memory size (which is 8gb as stated above).

Comment: Ah, the `0x24a5adff8` is out of range. And you can access the virtual address without crashing your program?

Comment: Thank you. How can I see there the physical memory addresses used by the kernel itself ? (The physical memory range I use in my kernel module)

Comment: I don't know a way to find out at which physical address in memory the kernel as installed itself. `/proc/modules` seems to contain virtual addresses, though. Also from the output of `/proc/iomem`, I think that the physical memory isn't continuous.